# SpecFlow generating two different code behind and one doesn't work

Tags: specflow

I have identical steps in two different SpecFlow feature files, like this:
[image]

When you right-click and go to the definition, they both go to this in a common step definition file:

```
        public void GivenUserNameOf(string userName)
        {
            SetUser(userName);
        }
```

However, when I check the generated code behind files, I see two different things:

```
 testRunner.Given(string.Format("user name of {0}", userName), ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
```

which is working, and this:

```
 testRunner.Given("user name of <userName>", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
```

which fails because the string that is passed in is userName (with angle brackets around it, editor thinks the brackets are link syntax, so I left them out) and it results in an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in my code.

I tried deleting the feature file and code behind file and recreating them, and tried deleting those files AND the cache file in the temp folder.  Every time, the new feature file code behind file still contains the bracketed text, rather than "{0}" as it should.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Please post the entire scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two scenarios was one was created as a Scenario Outline (the one that worked) and one was just a plain scenario.  When I changed the Scenario to a new Scenario Outline, it began working too.